# Connect Database to Excel via SSH tunnel

Tags: database, excel, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect Excel to my companies database but am running into problems because we use an SSH tunnel. The SSH tunnel connects to Nexcess which is where our servers are stored.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand this a little?  What errors are you seeing, etc...?

Comment: Sure here are my steps.   1. Open Excel and go to the Data Tab > Get External > From Other Sources.   2. Then I have a few options. I choose the "From SQL Server" option which seems to make sense. But I put in my credentials and the error I receive is "DBNETLIB ConnectionOpen Connect(() SQL Server does not exist or access denied". My credentials are valid though I am able to connect to our DB through MySQL. But in MySQL I can SSH tunnel where in this Excel option they dont have an option for that. Thanks for all the help by the way! This is my first time trying to make this happen.

Comment: UPDATE - I am suspicious we don't have external connections set up. I found this article that seems helpful. I will play with the settings and see what happens. http://leansoftware.net/Help/Excel-Database-Tasks/Worked-examples/How-to-connect-Excel-to-Remote-Web-Server-SQL-Data.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Use putty, set up your SSH link to the server.
- Under auth select 'allow agent forwarding'
- In tunnels set source port to 3306 and then put the domain of your mysql server in the destination followed by :3306 (update this port number if your mysql server is on a different port obviously, but keep the local port the same)
- Connect
- In mysql workbench, add a new connection: localhost, port 3306, user / pass etc
- Then from excel, connect away